# asp.net cookie does not persist

Tags: asp.net, cookies

While trying to persist a cookie for future reference, can't get it:

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(COOKIE_LMNOMBRE) 
{ 
   Domain = "SIG", Value = userName 
});
```

Checking on Firefox firebug, there is no cookie!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure about the domain name? Have you tried removing the domain name?

```
HttpCookie cookie = new(COOKIE_LMNOMBRE)
{ 
   Value = userName
};
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Comment: worked! the problem was the domain name, I removed it.